# ¿Cómo guardar "funciones" en la propiedad de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, function, onclick, vuetify

Tengo un arreglo de objetos:

```
dropdownButtons: [
  {name: 'nombre del boton 1', onclick: 'nombreDeLaFuncion1()'},
  {name: 'nombre del boton 2', onclick: 'nombreDeLaFuncion2()'},
  {name: 'nombre del boton 3', onclick: 'nombreDeLaFuncion3()'}
]
```

Uso un v-for para plasmar estos objetos en una lista desplegable (dropdown), pero no sé cómo lograr que al presionar el botón, ocurra la función guardada en la propiedad 'onclick'.

De momento solo se me ha ocurrido hacer esto en el componente, pero desde luego no funciona.

¿Que hago para plasmar la propiedad "onclick" como una función en el evento @click?

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-item-group>
    <v-list-item v-for="(ítem, index) in dropdownButtons" :key="index">
      <v-list-item-content @click="ítem.onclick">
        <v-list-item-title>
          {{item.name}}
        <v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item>
  <v-list-item-group>
<v-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar la funcion flecha para pasar el item actual para enviarlo a la funcion:

```
<v-list-item-content @click="{(item)=>myFunction(item)}">
```